# Get page url, remove a string from URL, use new url for embed src

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, embed

I am using Google Drive PDF viewer to embed PDF files in HTML pages.

I am doing multiple operations to modify the PDF URL to embed accordingly to certain conditions and store it into a variable.
But finally, I cannot input the final URL in the embed src field.

This is the entire script:

```
<embed id="pdfDrive" src="temporary" width="100%" height="100%">

<script>
 var pdfURL = window.location.href;
 pdfURL.replace('/abbac.html?file=', '/');
 var driveURL1 = 'https://drive.google.com/viewerng/'

 finalURL = driveURL1 + 'viewer?embedded=true&url=' + pdfURL;
 finalURL.replace('/abbac.html?file=', '/');
 alert(finalURL.replace('/viewer.html?file=', '/'));

 document.getElementById('pdfDrive').src = finalURL;
</script>
```

**Alert** returns the **correct URL** (**finalURL** is absolute url https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=https://www.andreadd.it/appunti/polimi/ingegneria/corsi/en_mec_aes/comuni/anno1/analisi%20I/appunti/Appunti_riassuntivi.pdf) but finalURL variable is not correctly given to **src**.

Embedded windows test is: 404 not found: URL requested     https://www.andreadd.it:443/appunti/polimi/ingegneria/corsi/en_mec_aes/comuni/anno1/analisi%20I/temporary

src="temporary" is not updated with **finalURL**

Thank you

Comment: It perfectly works on my browser (chrome latest), What browser and version you are using

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `setAttribute` on the fetched element.

For example - In your case, it would be like

```
const pdfDrive = document.getElementById('pdfDrive')
pdfDrive.setAttribute('src', finalURL)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that

```
finalURL.replace('/viewer.html?file=', '/')
```

was not enough.

I solved with another additional variable:

```
finalURL2 = finalURL.replace('/viewer.html?file=', '/')
```

and then used finalURL2.

Thank you